# Limit HTML tags generated by JS

Tags: javascript, tags, hashtag

JS code below catches words from an input as hashtags and turn them to HTML span tag. I just need to put limitation at the amount of words and span tags that are generated by user. For example 10 words. Moreover, by pressing space button the user can delete tags.

```js
const BACKSPACE = 8;
const ENTER = 32;
document.getElementById('tag-input').addEventListener('keydown', adjust);

function adjust(e) {
  const val = e.target.value;

  if (e.keyCode === BACKSPACE && !val) {
    deleteTag();
  }

  if (e.keyCode === ENTER && val) {
    e.target.value = '';
    addTag(val);
  }

  const textLength = textLengthToPx(val);
  const inputWidth = e.target.offsetWidth;
  const minThreshold = 1;
  const maxThreshold = 200;
  const delta = inputWidth - textLength;
  const shouldGrow = delta < minThreshold;
  const shouldShrink = delta > maxThreshold;

  if (shouldGrow) {
    setStyle(e.target, 'width', '90%');
  } else if (shouldShrink) {
    e.target.style = '';
  }
}

function deleteTag() {
  document.querySelectorAll('#tags > span')[document.querySelectorAll('#tags > span').length - 1].remove();
}

function addTag(val) {
  const input = document.getElementById('tag-input');
  const tag = document.createElement('span');
  const tagsContainer = document.getElementById('tags');
  tag.className = 'tag';
  tag.innerHTML = val;
  let counter = 0;
  while (counter <= 5) {
    tagsContainer.insertBefore(tag, input);
    counter++;
  }
}

function setStyle(node, rule, value) {
  node.style = `${rule}:${value}`;
}

function textLengthToPx(text) {
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML = text;
  span.className = 'invisible';
  return span.offsetWidth;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="tag-input"></textarea>
```

Comment: I think you need to add html ([mcve]) and add what issues you are facing. What is example input, what is expected output, what is current output, etc

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add whatever is necessary to create the [mcve] already requested

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by adding a counter.